# How to include PHP library in Python package (on not do it)

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, pip, composer-php

I've created tool, that runs as a server, and allow clients to connect to it through TCP, and run some commands. It's written on python 3
Now I'm going to build package and upload it to Pypi, and have conceptual problem.
This tool have python client library inside, so, after installation of the package, it'll be possible to just import library into python script, and use for connection to the daemon without dealing with raw TCP/IP.
Also, I have PHP library, for connection to me server, and the problem is - **I don't know how to include it into my python package the right way**.
Variants, that I found and can't choose the right one:

- Just include library.php file into package, and after running "pip install my_package", I would write "require('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/my_package/library.php')" into my php file. This way allows to distribute library with the server, and update it synchronously, but add long ugly paths to php require instruction.
- As library.php in placed on github repository, I could just publish it's url in the docs, and it'll be possible to just clone repository. It makes possible to clone repo, and update library by git pull.
- Create separate package with my library.php, upload it into packagist, and use composer to download it when it's needed. Good for all composer users, and allow manual update, but doens't update with server's package.

Maybe I've missed some other variants.

I want to know what would be true python'ic and php'ic way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: The server component is entirely independent, install it as such. When I install a Python client somewhere, I don't expect the server to come along.

Comment: The server has client inside of it, because it's used to control server. For example, when I run my_server stop, it actually runs as a client, connect to running server instance, and tell it, that is should shutdown. So, python client library is a part of the tool.

Comment: Yes, but do you have to run that client *on the same machine*?

Comment: No, there a config file and command line options, that help to choose where does server running, so client could be used on other machine. The tool itself is quite small, so server, client, config reading class, and console command class are all in a single file 1380 lines long (with docstrings), so from the beginning, It was intended as a single-file simple script, that have all the things build-in

Comment: That still doesn't mean you want to install both on the same machine all the time. They are separate pieces, install them separately.

Comment: Ok, and, as I see, your advice for my dilemma would be "create separate php package for library.php, so user could use composer to install it separately from python package"

Comment: I have no experience with PHP packaging, sorry, so I can't advice on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to create separate PHP package for my PHP library, and upload it to a packagist.org, so, user could get it using php composer, but not forced to, as it would be in case of including library.php into python package.